# set default option selected value based on time of day

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an form that creates a function and sets a daily time to do that function.

I want to change the 'selected' value I set at 07:00 to select that based on the user's current time, rounded up to the next hour.

Any ideas how I can best accomplish that in javascript or using jQuery mod?

Here's the markup sample, just to give you a visual of sorts.

In other word, instead of:

```
<option value="07:00" selected>7:00 am</option>
```

it would just be:

```
<option value="07:00">7:00 am</option>
```

... like the rest of the options values, but would select for the user a default based on the next available hour on their local time.

Here's the full list if it would provide a better example:

```
<select id="ExecutionTime" name="ExecutionTime">
<option value="00:00">12:00 am</option><option value="01:00">1:00 am</option><option value="02:00">2:00 am</option><option value="03:00">3:00 am</option><option value="04:00">4:00 am</option><option value="05:00">5:00 am</option><option value="06:00">6:00 am</option><option value="07:00" selected>7:00 am</option><option value="08:00">8:00 am</option><option value="09:00">9:00 am</option><option value="10:00">10:00 am</option><option value="11:00">11:00 am</option><option value="12:00">12:00 pm</option><option value="13:00">1:00 pm</option><option value="14:00">2:00 pm</option><option value="15:00">3:00 pm</option><option value="16:00">4:00 pm</option><option value="17:00">5:00 pm</option><option value="18:00">6:00 pm</option><option value="19:00">7:00 pm</option><option value="20:00">8:00 pm</option><option value="21:00">9:00 pm</option><option value="22:00">10:00 pm</option><option value="23:00">11:00 pm</option>                  
</select>
```

Am I nuts or can this be easily done in js?

Comment: Would new Date().getHours(); work? Or does it have to be a non 24 clock?

Answer (score 2):

This will automatically populate the dropdown, and then select the current hour.

```
var d = new Date().getHours(); // get the hour in 24 hour format
var a = d > 11 ? "pm" : "am"; /// get AM or PM
var hour = ((d + 11) % 12 + 1); // Convert 24 hours to 12 
selectList.val(hour + ':00 ' + a); // Set the dropdowns selected value
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sa9nqfxm/

Comment: It should be `var a = d > 11 ? "pm" : "am"; `

Comment: Oh that's perfect - I wondered about the math diff, 12 hours off.  the correction above fixes that.

Comment: Adding to what you did, I put in a ready function and monkeyed with the time and vars a little.  This works fine but for some reason when I plugged into my page, it doesn't actually populate the form.  Not sure why... will have to play with it more.     http://jsfiddle.net/karixa/zx292xom/

Comment: You dont need a ready statement in JSFiddle, if you look at the dropdown onder the jquery dropdown it has that option.

Comment: This worked well actually - but I have some other js conflicting my page so it's actually wiping out what I had.  JS can be a real pill sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

```
var now = new Date();
var curHour = now.getHours();
if (now.getMinutes() != 0) {
    curHour = (curHour + 1) % 24; // round up
}
var hourString = (curHour < 10 ? "0" : "") + curHour + ":00";
$("#ExecutionTime option[value='"+hourString+"']").attr('selected', true);
$("#ExecutionTime option:not([value='"+hourString+"'])").attr('selected', false);
```

Comment: Barmar, I didn't really understand so was using the other, but wanted to your bit out too.  I was trying to fiddle it but can't get it to work.  Where i am I going wrong here? http://jsfiddle.net/karixa/bk1r3yo7/

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectList = $('#selectDropdown');
for(var i =0; i < 24; i++){
    var hour = ((i + 11) % 12 + 1);
    var a = i > 11 ? "pm" : "am";
    selectList.append('<option value="'+ hour + ':00 '+a+'" >'+ hour + ':00 '+a+'</option>');        
}

var d = new Date().getHours();
var a = i > 11 ? "pm" : "am";
var hour = ((d + 11) % 12 + 1);
selectList.val(hour + ':00 ' + a);
```